# Nested IFs to send emails vis VBA

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am trying to complete some VBA to send an email to different people based on set criteria(1, 2 or 3).

I can get the email to send on an IF with the first part but cannot get it to include the different criteria.

```
    Dim OutlookApp As Object
    Dim OutlookMail As Object
    Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutlookMail = OutlookApp.CreateItem(0)

    If Sheets("Master").Range("D18") = 1 Then
        ActiveWorkbook.Save
        On Error Resume Next
        With OutlookMail
            .To = "x1@1.co.uk"
            .CC = "x1@1.co.uk"
            .BCC = ""
            .Subject = "Holiday Response"
            .Body = "Hi, please find attached the requested Holiday thank you." & vbNewLine & Signature
            .Attachments.Add Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName
            .Send

    ElseIf Sheets("Master").Range("D18") = 2 Then
        ActiveWorkbook.Save
        On Error Resume Next
        With OutlookMail
            .To = "x2@2.co.uk"
            .CC = "x2@2.co.uk"
            .BCC = ""
            .Subject = "Holiday Response"
            .Body = "Hi, please find attached the requested Holiday thank you." & vbNewLine & Signature
            .Attachments.Add Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName
            .Send

    Else
        ActiveWorkbook.Save
        On Error Resume Next
        With OutlookMail
            .To = "x3@3.co.uk"
            .CC = "x3@3.co.uk"
            .BCC = ""
            .Subject = "Holiday Response"
            .Body = "Hi, please find attached the requested Holiday thank you." & vbNewLine & Signature
            .Attachments.Add Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName
            .Send
        End With

        Set OutlookMail = Nothing
        Set OutlookApp = Nothing
    End If
End Sub
```

Email will send to different people based on the different criteria being met.

Error message currently shows Compile Error: Else without If

Comment: Please indent the code properly, sometimes good indentation is all you need to spot the error. For example don't you need to `end` your `with`s?

Comment: Hi, It is indented in VBA but didn't allow it to paste in correctly, I am pretty basic on VBA, apologies

Comment: Note that you use `On Error Resume Next` wrong. This line hides all error messages but if errors occur you will not notice them but they break your code. Remove them and fix your errors instead. Or implement a real error handling: [VBA Error Handling – A Complete Guide](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-error-handling). • If you use the code like it is you will not be notified if anything goes wrong. It reads like *"try to send an email but if it fails don't tell anyone a word, just act if it was successful"*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were missing some `End With` in your code. You can also avoid repeating all these unnecessary lines of code and simplify a little bit. This will work:

```
Dim OutlookApp As Object
Dim OutlookMail As Object
Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutlookMail = OutlookApp.CreateItem(0)

ActiveWorkbook.Save

With OutlookMail
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "Holiday Response"
    .Body = "Hi, please find attached the requested Holiday thank you." & vbNewLine & Signature
    .Attachments.Add Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName

    If Sheets("Master").Range("D18") = 1 Then
        .To = "x1@1.co.uk"
        .CC = "x1@1.co.uk"
    ElseIf Sheets("Master").Range("D18") = 2 Then
        .To = "x2@2.co.uk"
        .CC = "x2@2.co.uk"
    Else
        .To = "x3@3.co.uk"
        .CC = "x3@3.co.uk"
    End If

    'Here use a proper error handling
    'On Error Resume Next
    .Send
End With

Set OutlookMail = Nothing
Set OutlookApp = Nothing
```

> **Note**: As already stated, you need to implement a proper `error handling` in case of failure sending your mail.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You can put the `With OutlookMail` outside the `If`s and then only do it once.

Comment: Perfect thanks guys, I will try end separate and order moving forward to spot the mistake.

Comment: Also `.subject` to `.send` should be outside of the ifs. There is lots of unnecessary repeated code here. And should `Set OutlookMail = Nothing` not come even after the `End With`?

Comment: … and `On Error Resume Next` should be removed or replaced by proper error handling.